# Error al intentar crear un Curriculo en PDF

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo que crear un pdf con el curriculo de una persona.
Tienen que poner los datos de esa persona, cursos de formación e idiomas realizados y su experiencia laboral.

Usuario:

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('second_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('provincia')->nullable();
        $table->string('localidad')->nullable();
        $table->string('direccion')->nullable();
        $table->string('telefono');
        $table->string('dni');
        $table->boolean('vehiculo')->default(false);
        $table->string('foto')->default('anonimo.jpg');
        $table->boolean('activado')->default(false); // Se marca aqui como falso y ya se pone automaticamente así al hacer el formulario.
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Cursos de formación:

```
Schema::create('formacions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->string('grado');
        $table->string('centro');
        $table->boolean('finalizacion');
        $table->unsignedInteger('anyio_finalizacion')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Cursos de idioma:

```
Schema::create('idiomas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('idioma');
        $table->string('nivel_hablado');
        $table->string('nivel_escrito');
        $table->string('titulo_oficial');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index(['user_id', 'idioma']);
    });
```

Experiencia laboral:

```
Schema::create('experiencias', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('puesto');
        $table->string('funcion_realizada');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector_empresa');
        $table->string('mes_anyo_inicio');
        $table->string('mes_anyo_fin');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Todo esto se maneja con la siguiente función:

```
public function exportar(User $usuario){
        $formaciones=$usuario->formacion;
        $idiomas=$usuario->idiomas;
        $experiencias=$usuario->experiencias;

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.curriculo', compact('usuario','idiomas','formaciones','experiencias'));
        return $pdf->download('Curriculo de '.$usuario->name.' '.$usuario->second_name.".pdf");
    }
```

Y el curriculo se genera en esta vista:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<html lang="es">
<body>
    <font size="17" style="display: inline;">Datos del usuario</font> <img style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" align="right" src="{{url($usuario->ruta())}}"/>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Residencia</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Vehiculo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $usuario->name }} {{ $usuario->second_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->direccion }} ({{ $usuario->localidad }}, {{ $usuario->provincia }})</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->telefono }}</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->dni }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if($usuario->vehiculo)
                        Es poseedor de vehiculo propio
                    @else
                        No posee vehiculo propio
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php
        $forma=count($formaciones);
        $exp=count($experiencias);
        $idi=count($idiomas);
    ?>

    @if($forma>0)
        <h3>Cursos realizados</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Grado</th>
                    <th>Centro</th>
                    <th>Finalización</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @forelse($formaciones as $formacion)
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>$formacion->titulo</td>
                        <td>$formacion->grado</td>
                        <td>$formacion->centro</td>
                        <td>
                            @if($formacion->finalizacion)
                                $formacion->anyio_finalizacion
                            @else
                                No
                            @endif
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No ha hecho ningun curso formativo</h3>
    @endif

    @if($exp>0)
        <h3>Idiomas estudiados</h3>
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Idioma</th>
                    <th>Nivel de habla</th>
                    <th>Nivel de escritura</th>
                    <th>Titulo oficial</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @forelse($idiomas as $idioma)
                <tbody>
                    <td>$idioma->idioma</td>
                    <td>$idioma->nivel_hablado</td>
                    <td>$idioma->nivel_escrito</td>
                    <td>$idioma->titulo_oficial</td>
                </tbody>
            @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No ha estudiado ningun idioma</h3>
    @endif

    @if($idi>0)
        <h3>Experiencia Laboral</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Puesto</th>
                <th>Función realizada</th>
                <th>Empresa</th>
                <th>Sector</th>
                <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
                <th>Fecha de finalización</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @forelse($experiencias as $experiencia)
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>$experiencia->puesto</td>
                    <td>$experiencia->funcion_realizada</td>
                    <td>$experiencia->empresa</td>
                    <td>$experiencia->sector_empresa</td>
                    <td>$experiencia->mes_anyo_inicio</td>
                    <td>$experiencia->mes_anyo_fin</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No tiene experiencia laboral</h3>
    @endif
</body>
</html>
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto me topo con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo curioso es que veo esa linea y no veo un @endif, sino un @endforelse.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he logrado solucionarlo.
Al final resulta que al usar un condicional o un bucle, es obligatorio el uso de @else o @empty.
Así queda la vista del PDF:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<html lang="es">
<body>
    <font size="17" style="display: inline;">Datos del usuario</font> <img style="width: 60px; height: 60px;" align="right" src="{{url($usuario->ruta())}}"/>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Residencia</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Vehiculo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $usuario->name }} {{ $usuario->second_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->direccion }} ({{ $usuario->localidad }}, {{ $usuario->provincia }})</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->telefono }}</td>
                <td>{{ $usuario->dni }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if($usuario->vehiculo)
                        Es poseedor de vehiculo propio
                    @else
                        No posee vehiculo propio
                    @endif
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php
        $forma=count($formaciones);
        $exp=count($experiencias);
        $idi=count($idiomas);
    ?>

    @if($forma>0)
        <h3>Cursos realizados</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Titulo</th>
                    <th>Grado</th>
                    <th>Centro</th>
                    <th>Finalización</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @forelse($formaciones as $formacion)
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$formacion->titulo}}</td>
                        <td>{{$formacion->grado}}</td>
                        <td>{{$formacion->centro}}</td>
                        <td>
                            @if($formacion->finalizacion)
                                {{$formacion->anyio_finalizacion}}
                            @else
                                No
                            @endif
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            @empty
                Se ha producido un error
            @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No ha hecho ningun curso formativo</h3>
    @endif

    @if($exp>0)
        <h3>Idiomas estudiados</h3>
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Idioma</th>
                    <th>Nivel de habla</th>
                    <th>Nivel de escritura</th>
                    <th>Titulo oficial</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @forelse($idiomas as $idioma)
                <tbody>
                    <td>{{$idioma->idioma}}</td>
                    <td>{{$idioma->nivel_hablado}}</td>
                    <td>{{$idioma->nivel_escrito}}</td>
                    <td>{{$idioma->titulo_oficial}}</td>
                </tbody>
            @empty
                Se ha producido un error
            @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No ha estudiado ningun idioma</h3>
    @endif

    @if($idi>0)
        <h3>Experiencia Laboral</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Puesto</th>
                <th>Función realizada</th>
                <th>Empresa</th>
                <th>Sector</th>
                <th>Fecha de inicio</th>
                <th>Fecha de finalización</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @forelse($experiencias as $experiencia)
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->puesto}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->funcion_realizada}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->empresa}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->sector_empresa}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->mes_anyo_inicio}}</td>
                    <td>{{$experiencia->mes_anyo_fin}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        @empty
            Se ha producido un error
        @endforelse
        </table>
    @else
        <h3>No tiene experiencia laboral</h3>
    @endif
</body>
</html>
```